# Does read.csv have any memory implications?

Tags: r

When you use read.csv, does the file stay in memory? If so, how can I close it so as to avoid any memory crashes when reading many csv files?

Comment: I believe read_csv from `readr` can handle more memory.

Comment: If you are reading a huge CSV file, forget about `utils::read.table` -- you get several orders of magnitude speedup from eg `data.table::fread`, but the data should fit in the physical memory. If dealing with even larger files, check eg the `sqldf` package, `read.csv.ffdf` from `ff` or `read.big.matrix` from `bigmemory`.

Comment: Thank you @Carl, currently I am using the skipNul and sep parameters in read.csv. Do you know if readr offers similar parameters?

Comment: @daroczig not exactly trying to read a huge file but rather reading about 30000 small csv files one by one and merging them together in one dataframe. For this reason, it would be great if I could just close them after appending their data to my dataframe

Comment: You'd have to look at the documentation to see the parameters for read_csv: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/readr.pdf

Comment: @jgozal dynamically extending a `data.frame` (like `rbind` 30K times) will be slow -- not only due to parsing the CSV, but doing many (unnecessary) copies in memory. Instead, you could `rbindlist` the list of objects returned by the `fread` calls, or if the structure of the files is the same, I'd simply `cat` the files together in bash before reading the files (getting rid of the header from the separate files if needed) for improved performance.